# How Can I create the server in Pgadmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I haven't get default localhost server after installing pgAdmin4. And then I tried to create new server with 127.0.0.1 and localhost using 5432 port. But it says the it can not connect to that server and gives this error.

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

if anyone have an idea or solutions to create server please help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you install Postgres on your computer? If yes, did you start it?

Comment: I installed pgAdmin4 only. Should I want to install postgress seperately?

Comment: Yes, pgAdmin is only a SQL _client_ that connects to a (running) Postgres _server_

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name. Now it is solved.